# Lastseen today or yesterday login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I get lastseen from database and i want to compare with date time now if match with today show Today if match with yesteday show Yesterday.

I try these code but not working

```
 Welcome back {{Auth::user()->name}} Your last here:
    @if (substr(Auth::user()->lastseen, 0, 10) === date('Y.m.d'))
        Today
    @elseif (substr(Auth::user()->lastseen, 0, 10) === date('Y.m.d', strtotime('-1 day')))
        Yesterday
    @else
        {{Auth::user()->lastseen}}
    @endif
```

Comment: How does `->lastseen` look like? How is it formatted?

Comment: @devk: lastseen format "Thu, Jan 4, 2018 8:11 AM"

Comment: Format it to `Y.m.d` format as well and then compare them

Comment: @devk: can you create answer for me?

Comment: Use Carbon to handle these things :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) like this:

```
@if (\Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->lastseen)->toDateString() === date('Y-m-d'))
    Today
@elseif (\Carbon\Carbon::parse(Auth::user()->lastseen)->toDateString() === date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')))
    Yesterday
@else
    {{Auth::user()->lastseen}}
@endif
```

But I suggest [casting `lastseen` to date](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) so you can get rid of `\Carbon\Carbon::parse(...)` part in the view.

Comment: I got an error "Call to a member function toDateString() on string"

Comment: @TheRock It should work now. `)` was misplaced in the `@if`